# Value Errors When Retrieving Images With Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm having trouble using Scrapy's image pipeline to retrieve images. From the error reports, I think I am feeding Scrapy the right image_urls. However, instead of downloading images from them, Scrapy returns the error: ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h.

This is my first time using the image pipeline feature, so I suspect I'm making a simple mistake. All the same, I'd appreciate help solving it.

Below you'll find my spider, settings, items, and error output. They're not quite MWEs, but I think they're pretty simple and easy to understand all the same.

Spider:
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from ngamedallions.items import NgamedallionsItem
    from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst
    from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
    from scrapy.loader.processors import Join
    from scrapy.http import Request
    import re

```
class NGASpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ngamedallions'
    allowed_domains = ['nga.gov']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1312.html'
    ]

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('art-object-page.*','objects/*')),callback='parse_CatalogRecord',
    follow=True
    ),)

    def parse_CatalogRecord(self, response):
        CatalogRecord = ItemLoader(item=NgamedallionsItem(), response=response)
        CatalogRecord.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
        keywords = "medal|medallion"
        r = re.compile('.*(%s).*' % keywords, re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)
        if r.search(response.body_as_unicode()):
            CatalogRecord.add_xpath('title', './/dl[@class="artwork-details"]/dt[@class="title"]/text()')
            CatalogRecord.add_xpath('accession', './/dd[@class="accession"]/text()')
            CatalogRecord.add_xpath('inscription', './/div[@id="inscription"]/p/text()')
            CatalogRecord.add_xpath('image_urls', './/img[@class="mainImg"]/@src')

            return CatalogRecord.load_item()
```

Settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'ngamedallions'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['ngamedallions.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'ngamedallions.spiders'

DOWNLOAD_DELAY=3

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}

IMAGES_STORE = '/home/tricia/Documents/Programing/Scrapy/ngamedallions/medallionimages'
```

Items:

```
import scrapy

class NgamedallionsItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    accession = scrapy.Field()
    inscription = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Error Log:

```
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5.post2+ga046ce8 started (bot: ngamedallions)
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'ngamedallions.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'items.json', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['ngamedallions.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'ngamedallions', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3}
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ImagesPipeline
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-04-24 19:00:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1312.html> (referer: None)
2016-04-24 19:00:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1.html> (referer: None)
2016-04-24 19:00:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1312.html> (referer: http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1312.html)
2016-04-24 19:00:48 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'accession': u'1942.9.163.a',
 'image_urls': u'http://media.nga.gov/public/objects/1/3/1/2/1312-primary-0-440x400.jpg',
 'inscription': u'around circumference: IOHANNES FRANCISCVS GON MA; around bottom circumference: MANTVA',
 'title': u'Gianfrancesco Gonzaga di Rodigo, 1445-1496, Lord of Bozzolo, Sabbioneta, and Viadana 1478 [obverse]'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 44, in process_item
requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 109, in get_media_requests
return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.IMAGES_URLS_FIELD, [])]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 24, in __init__
self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 55, in _set_url
self._set_url(url.encode(self.encoding))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 59, in _set_url
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
2016-04-24 19:00:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1312.html> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2016-04-24 19:00:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1313.html> (referer: http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1312.html)
2016-04-24 19:00:52 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'accession': u'1942.9.163.b',
 'image_urls': u'http://media.nga.gov/public/objects/1/3/1/3/1313-primary-0-440x400.jpg',
 'inscription': u'around top circumference: TRINACRIA IANI; upper center: PELORVS ; across center: PA LI; across bottom: BELAVRA',
 'title': u'House between Two Hills [reverse]'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
 File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 44, in process_item
requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 109, in get_media_requests
return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.IMAGES_URLS_FIELD, [])]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 24, in __init__
self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 55, in _set_url
self._set_url(url.encode(self.encoding))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 59, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
2016-04-24 19:00:55 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1.html> (referer: http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb/Collection/art-object-page.1.html)
2016-04-24 19:01:02 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-04-24 19:01:02 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1609,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 125593,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 5,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 5,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 24, 23, 1, 2, 938181),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 24, 23, 0, 40, 851598)}
2016-04-24 19:01:02 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TakeFirst processor is making `image_urls` a string when it should be a list.

Add:

```
CatalogRecord.image_urls_out = lambda v: v
```

EDIT:

This could also be:

```
CatalogRecord.image_urls_out = scrapy.loader.processors.Identity()
```